# Whatsapp Javascript

Tags: javascript, automation, console, whatsapp

Okay so dumb question: So I wanna semi-automate sending messages on WhatsApp to spam friends. I have access to the "send button", but that's not the problem. My problem is the input-field. I can actually find the input.class and also assign a variable to it, but I just don't know how to add Value to it. A simple var.value; wouldn't give me access to the value unfortunately. I wanna use a for loop and send maybe a 100 messages at once

Comment: please share your attempt please.

Comment: This sounds like a sure-fire way to get your whatsapp account blocked...

Comment: Does WhatsApp use some kind of botdetection?

Comment: I really didn't come that far with it, I could only click the button, but not add value to the input

Comment: Bot detection, rate limiting, I'm sure they considered that.